# Do Lords in the Cabinet have to answer questions in the House of Commons?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, house-of-commons, cabinet

Nicky Morgan has been retained as Secretary of State for Digital, Culture, Media and Sport. However, she is no longer an MP, but has been given a peerage instead.

As Cabinet members ordinarily answer questions from MPs in the House of Commons regarding their respective departments, will she have to make an appearance? Or else, will she have to answer questions in the "other place", with a junior minister deputising for her in the Commons?

Comment: Are you asking whether she will answer questions, or whether she will appear in the Commons debate chamber? The 'other place' in this case is just on the opposite end of the Palace of Westminster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ministers (including the Secretary of State) from each department answer questions from whichever house they belong to.

Normally, Secretaries of State are MPs, with some ministers from each department who are MPs and other who are peers, so that questions relating to that department can be answered in either house.

If the SoS is a peer, then the same arrangement holds - and yes, a minister from the department who is an MP will take the place of the SoS in the Commons.

Note that when dealing with the regular departmental question time in the Commons (though not when taking questions after a statement), it's normal for some questions to be answered by the SoS, and others to be answered by ministers, just to share the load.